# Make radio button inactive from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

THis is my controller

```
   public ActionResult radio()
    {
        return View();

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult radio(item it)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and this is my view

```
@model trydropdown.Models.item
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "radio"; 
}

<h2>radio</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("radio", "Home"))
{
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.buyable, "1",true)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.buyable, "2",false)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.buyable, "3",false)

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

I want to disable one radio button from actionresult radio .How

Comment: Disabled controls do not post back. (And your code is binding 3 radio buttons to property `buyable` all with the value `true`!)

Comment: `one radio button` but in your code you are disabling all the radiobuttons?

Comment: It was by mistake. I have edited. among the three radio buttons i need to disable one from controller.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you didn't pass any model to the view from your action.

After that, To disable the radio button you can simply pass a parameter in `Viewbag` or add a parameter to your model indicating the availability of this radio button.

for example :

```
@{
  var myAttrs = (ViewBag.Foo == true) ? new { disabled="disabled" } : null;
}

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.buyable, "1", myAttrs)
```

As I said above, instead of `ViewBag.Foo` you can have a parameter inside your view model.